# How to format a vaadin text field to display currency in $x,xxx format

Tags: polymer, vaadin

I want to use the vaadin text field with polymer and I want the text to be auto formatted to money format like $4,500 or $10,000 while user is typing. I am able to get the prefix and numbers only but not the comma.

`<vaadin-text-field prevent-invalid-input pattern="[0-9]*" style = "width: 6em"><div slot="prefix">$</div> </vaadin-text-field>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `vaadin-text-field` does not have any direct property or way to do this. I made a workaround by making a component wrapper for it. Basically, it validates input as users type and adds commas in the right place. It's compatible with `.` as input as well. Use the property `comma` to turn the feature on and off. The repo link is below.

https://github.com/binhbbbb/comma-field

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NumeralFieldFormatter](https://github.com/johanneshayry/textfieldformatter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/textfieldformatter/NumeralFieldFormatter.java) from the vaadin addon [TextField Formatter](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/textfield-formatter):

```
new NumberFieldFormatter(",", ".", 3).extend(myNumberField);
```